# parse json and add fields to Data frame in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, databricks

I have a notebook that queries API and gets the JSON back as per the attached format.

```
[{
   "display_name":"IST-XXX1",
   "members":[
      {
         "aad_id":"XXX",
         "user_principal_name":"XXXX@XX.com",
         "user_principal_name_normalized":"XXXX@XX.com",
         "mail":"XXXX@XX.com"
      },
      {
         "aad_id":"XXXX",
         "user_principal_name":"XXXX@XX.com",
         "user_principal_name_normalized":"XXXX@XX.com",
         "mail":"XXXX@XX.com"
      },
      {
         "aad_id":"XXXXX",
         "user_principal_name":"XXXX@XX.com",
         "user_principal_name_normalized":"XXXX@XX.com",
         "mail":"XXXX@XX.com"
      },
      {
         "aad_id":"XXXX",
         "user_principal_name":"XXXX@XX.com",
         "user_principal_name_normalized":"XXXX@XX.com",
         "mail":"XXXX@XX.com"
      },
      {
         "aad_id":"XXXX",
         "user_principal_name":"XXXX@XX.com",
         "user_principal_name_normalized":"XXXX@XX.com",
         "mail":"XXXX@XX.com"
      }
   ],
   "id":"XXX"
}]
```

I would then need to parse the the json and add values like display_name and Mail from the JSON into a data frame so it can insert it in the SQL database as rows (display name will be repeated depending on the entries of how many mails are in the list).

Please help me achieve this in python.

Note: Code that I tried to parse is as below but its not aligning them as per group vs email properly

```
 for i in item_generator(response_data, "display_name"):
            ans = {"display_name": i}
            output.append(ans)
        for i in item_generator(response_data, "mail"):
            ans = {"mail": i}
            output.append(ans)
        print(output)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all i dont really understand why you do a loop on the `display_name` your json only have one.

But.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {"display_name":"IST-XXX1","members":[{"aad_id":"XXX","user_principal_name":"XXXX@XX.com","user_principal_name_normalized":"XXXX@XX.com","mail":"XXXX@XX.com"},{"aad_id":"XXXX","user_principal_name":"XXXX@XX.com","user_principal_name_normalized":"XXXX@XX.com","mail":"XXXX@XX.com"},{"aad_id":"XXXXX","user_principal_name":"XXXX@XX.com","user_principal_name_normalized":"XXXX@XX.com","mail":"XXXX@XX.com"},{"aad_id":"XXXX","user_principal_name":"XXXX@XX.com","user_principal_name_normalized":"XXXX@XX.com","mail":"XXXX@XX.com"},{"aad_id":"XXXX","user_principal_name":"XXXX@XX.com","user_principal_name_normalized":"XXXX@XX.com","mail":"XXXX@XX.com"}],"id":"XXX"}

display_name = data['display_name']
members = data['members']

output = []
for member in members:
    mail = member['mail']
    output.append({'display_name': display_name, 'mail': mail})


df = pd.DataFrame(output)

print(df)
```

This will give you an list of your email "linked" to your display name.

Comment: Thank you, How do adjust the code to fit the Json object (to pass to data)

Comment: I'm not quite sure to understand what you're asking.

Comment: My api response is a JSON object. not a string. How do I adjust the code you provided to achieve same results with JSON object parsing.

Comment: if you response is already a JSON object just skip the `json.loads` part i edited my comment in this way

Comment: HI @Mougnou, I tried the code as is and I get the error as "list indices must be integers or slices, not str". Also I need to attach the results to the dataframe so I tried this df1= pd.DataFrame(output)
            return df1 and still same error. Please help

Comment: Your passing a list into data and not your json do something like that `data= yourApiResponse[0]`  and the creation of the dataframe you shared in comment is correct just fix what you put in `data` and it will work fine. I edited my comment in this way.

Comment: Hi @Mougnou, My data is like the sample from original post, [{"display_name":"IST-XXX1","members":[{"aad_id":"XXX","user_principal_name":"XXXX@XX.com",........,"id":"XXX"}]   its appended with Open and close brackets. Now my code is like data = overrides.json()
            display_name = data['display_name']
            members = data['members']

            output = []
            for member in members:
                mail = member['mail']
                output.append({'display_name': display_name, 'mail': mail})

            df = pd.DataFrame(output)
            print(df)

Comment: Please refer to my comment above, as per above I am getting same error like list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: Hi @Mougnou, The JSON object is list of dictionaries. like there will be multiple sets of displays names and its members.

Comment: I have tried this and it worked fine now.  response_data = overrides.json()

            output = []
            for item in response_data:
                display_name = item['display_name']
                members = item['members']
                for member in members:
                    mail = member.get('mail', None)
                    output.append({'display_name': display_name, 'mail': mail})

            df = pd.DataFrame(output)
            return df

Answer (score 0):

You can give json to pandas directly. But it cannot handle nested dictionaries.

let's assign your json to a variable called **data**.

```
import pandas as pd 
    data= {
           "display_name":"IST-XXX1",
           "members":[
              {
                 "aad_id":"XXX",
                 "user_principal_name":"XXXX@XX.com",
                 "user_principal_name_normalized":"XXXX@XX.com",
                 "mail":"XXXX@XX.com"
              },
              {
                 "aad_id":"XXXX",
                 "user_principal_name":"XXXX@XX.com",
                 "user_principal_name_normalized":"XXXX@XX.com",
                 "mail":"XXXX@XX.com"
              },
              {
                 "aad_id":"XXXXX",
                 "user_principal_name":"XXXX@XX.com",
                 "user_principal_name_normalized":"XXXX@XX.com",
                 "mail":"XXXX@XX.com"
              },
              {
                 "aad_id":"XXXX",
                 "user_principal_name":"XXXX@XX.com",
                 "user_principal_name_normalized":"XXXX@XX.com",
                 "mail":"XXXX@XX.com"
              },
              {
                 "aad_id":"XXXX",
                 "user_principal_name":"XXXX@XX.com",
                 "user_principal_name_normalized":"XXXX@XX.com",
                 "mail":"XXXX@XX.com"
              }
           ],
           "id":"XXX"
        }
```

and then put this into a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

[image]

Now you need to split member column:

```
df_parsed = df.join(pd.json_normalize(df['members'])).drop('members', axis='columns')
```

and it's ready!
[image]

Comment: Thank you, I am getting error like ''list' object has no attribute 'join''. My json same as the one you listed but enclosed with open and close brackets.

Comment: 'list' object has no attribute 'values' - is the error message

Comment: Updated my original post for JSON.